strange bug with news extension causes missing images/links on a particular multilanguage site
I have a strange bug at my typo v11 with news extension on a multilanguage site (LB=0, FR=3, DE=4, PT=5, EN=6 and fallback mode to LB) and I don't know when it started. On only one of the pages of the translated french site with list view, all images are missing for the news records and for any content-elements (not related to the news plugin) every link is missing.
While translations in DE and PT work fine, even when they were created afterwards. The FR page was working fine when it was published.
I tried the following steps without success: deleting the translated page, flushing the cache and re-creating the page again; disabling some or all content-elements on that page does not have any effect (buggy content elements still appear).
Is there a chance some news records could provoke a bug like this? Has anyone experienced this before?

In most browsers (like Firefox) there developer support (F12) where you see the communication. Also looking at the HTML page source might be enlightening. The image tags <img...> could have been placed in a non-visible HMTL spot.
